# When defining new type require you to have an alias name for it to compile?

Tags: c, typedef

**I got this code from Edubaca**

In line 12, Edubaca describes that `Course` took the alias name `course`, what is the reason for that and why is the syntax like that?
Also, is Courses in line 4 necessary?

What I've tried:

-Removing line 13 
-Change `Course` in lines 4 and 9 to `course`

```
#include <stdio.h>//Add all the basic C language libraries
#include <string.h>//Add the String library to perform string actions
//typedef for give struct keyword to user wanted keyword as like below (Courses)
typedef struct Course {
    char courseName[60];//declare character variable
    float CourseFee;//declare float variable
    char companyName[100];//declare character variable
    int loginID;//declare integer variable
} Course; //To make work user defined keyword we have call the keyword from here
//main method to execute application code
int main( ) {
    //Taken Courses name as course( alias name)
    Course course;
    //Copying character values into varaible
    strcpy(course.courseName, "C Programming");
    strcpy(course.companyName, "EDUCBA");
    //Initailize float values into varaible
    course.CourseFee = 5000.00;
    //Initailize integer values into varaible
    course.loginID=2452;
    //display the output of all the declared variable below
    printf( "Course Name : %s\n", course.courseName);
    printf( "Company Name : %s\n", course.companyName);
    printf( "Course Fee : %f\n", course.CourseFee);
    printf( "Login ID : %d\n", course.loginID);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is "alias name" supposed to mean here? `Course course;` creates a variable of type `Course` - the "alias name" comment about it is very confusing

Comment: @Anique I have understood nothing.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't have to `typedef` a structure and give it a new name, using the keyword `struct` together with the so-called "struct tag" is enough. In the example, the tag is `Course` so without the `typedef` the type would be called `struct Course`.

Using a `typedef` lets you abstract away, kind of, the exact details of the type which can be useful but it is not necessary, it's just a feature of the language.

You can use it with any type, for instance

```
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
```

would be a way of creating the C99 `<stdint.h>` type `uint16_t` if you knew that a `short` was the proper size for the particular compiler, and so on.

The line

```
Course course;
```

simply defines a variable called `course` of type `Course`, i.e. an instance of the structure. Without the `typedef` you would write

```
struct Course course;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use struct and not use typedef and an alias

```
#include <stdio.h>//Add all the basic C language libraries
#include <string.h>//Add the String library to perform string actions

//typedef for give struct keyword to user wanted keyword as like below (Courses)
struct Course {
    char courseName[60];//declare character variable
    float CourseFee;//declare float variable
    char companyName[100];//declare character variable
    int loginID;//declare integer variable
};

//main method to execute application code
int main( ) {
    //Taken Courses name as course( alias name)
    struct Course course;
    //Copying character values into varaible
    strcpy(course.courseName, "C Programming");
    strcpy(course.companyName, "EDUCBA");
    //Initailize float values into varaible
    course.CourseFee = 5000.00;
    //Initailize integer values into varaible
    course.loginID=2452;
    //display the output of all the declared variable below
    printf( "Course Name : %s\n", course.courseName);
    printf( "Company Name : %s\n", course.companyName);
    printf( "Course Fee : %f\n", course.CourseFee);
    printf( "Login ID : %d\n", course.loginID);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why "should"? Creating a `typedef` for a struct is a very common pattern, it sounds more like you wanted to write "could"

Comment: Yes it is very common, it is more to compile without alias